# Golang - Parsing nested JSON

Tags: go

I'm using the [go-worker](https://github.com/benmanns/goworker) to process resque jobs. A job has a payload which has a nested JSON structure like this:

```
[{
  "key-a":"val-a",
  "key-b":"val-b",
  "files":[{
    "key-a": [
      {"a":"b","c": "d"},
      {"e":"f","g": "h"}
    ],
    "key-b": [
      {"a":"b","c": "d"},
      {"e":"f","g": "h"}
    ]
  }]
}]
```

Now `go-worker` gives me `args ...interface{}` which represents that JSON payload, not the actual JSON text. Is there an idiomatic way to convert that(`args`) to the correct types (could use another package to do this.) Using type assertions manually seems a bit tedious for such a thing.

Comment: I've also asked this question as a [go-worker project issue](https://github.com/benmanns/goworker/issues/18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really giving you the actual go objects (i.e. a bunch of `map[string]interface{}` and not the json string itself) then there probably isn't much you can do besides a bunch of type assertions.

You could re-marshall it to json then parse it again into the correct structs, but that's a bit of a hack (and I have no idea if it would be performant or not).